# Diagonals at different points of a 2D list in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I was wondering how to get the list of values of diagonals that do not pass through the center.

Let's say I have a nested List:

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6][7,8,9]]
```

How would I, say, get the diagonal [2,6]?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not pass through the center" ?

Comment: What I mean is that the diagonal need not pass through the point 2,2 in this 2D list. How would get a diagonal that was off [1,5,8] or [3, 5, 7]?

Comment: Grab ALL the diagonals and remove those of length n ( =3 in your example)

Comment: But I'm not sure how to get the values of diagonals that are off-center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but this code gives you all the complete diagonals in each direction:

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
# number of rows, number of columns: ie L is m x n
m, n = len(L), len(L[0])

# Retreive the NE-SW (diag1) and NW-SE (diag2) diagonals
diag1 = []
diag2 = []
for p in range(m+n-1):
    diag1.append([])
    diag2.append([])
    q1 = 0
    if p >= n:
        q1 = p - n + 1
    q2 = m
    if p < m-1:
        q2 = p+1
    for q in range(q1, q2):
        x, y = p - q, q
        diag1[-1].append(L[y][x])
        # To get the other diagonal, read each row "backwards"
        x = n - x - 1
        diag2[-1].append(L[y][x])
print 'diag1:', diag1
print 'diag2:', diag2
```

That is:

```
diag1: [[1], [2, 4], [3, 5, 7], [6, 8], [9]]
diag2: [[3], [2, 6], [1, 5, 9], [4, 8], [7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you go about amending the code to accept non- m x n nested lists with the characteristic: len(L[i]) > len(L[i+1]).

For example, the following nested list:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15,16,17], 
[18,19,20,21,22], 
[23,24,25,26], 
[27,28], 
[29]]
```

should produce:

```
[[1], 
[2,11], 
[3,12,18], 
[4,13,19,23], 
[5,14,20,24,27], 
[6,15,21,25,28,29], 
[7,16,22,26], 
[8,17], 
[9], 
[10]
```